# solution for extra space in div element

Tags: html, css, cakephp

In my application I am using a `div` element. There is some extra space found below and above the div element.

How can I remove that?

Thanks

Comment: Please post some HTML so I can help you. Anything can happen to cause that extra spacing.

Answer (score 5):

Each browser has it's own default values for margin and padding on various elements. So unless you explicitly set eg.

```
div {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

in your CSS stylesheet, there will be some spacing below and above your div.

What's more annoying is that each different browser will have different default values for padding and margin on divs eg. Firefox might have 10px margin and IE may have 8px margin.

I find it is best to initially reset all these defaults to zero at the top of my stylesheets. eg.

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

In fact for this I use the brilliant [Blueprint CSS](http://blueprintcss.org/) as it has a reset.css file included which does the trick!

Comment: Instead of that long list, you can just use " * ".

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some margin applied to the div through some CSS style.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have access to the html of the page itself, try the `margin` or `padding` css styles on the tag.  For example

```
<div style="padding-top:0px;">my div with no padding at top</div>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp for more details

P.S. If you are using firefox [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) is a great tool to check / change these values and see what happens to your page

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are margins or padding given to the div elements via CSS. Skim your CSS file for something like this:

```
div {
    margin: [...];
    padding: [...];
}
```

Just get rid of the margin/padding definition or adjust the value as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;">My div has no padding</div>
```

If you're going to do this regularly, create a class for it in your CSS file instead.

Answer (score 0):

when you are wrapping some element with a div and if the div has unexpected extra space, you can simply apply `display: flex` to the div. thus, the extra space will be gone.

for example,

```
<div className="logo">
  <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
</div>

/* in css */
.logo {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).