# Remove Jquery Mobile White Space After the Content

Tags: jquery, mobile

I cannot remove the white space appearing after the content, my Jquery code was too long however i did manage to reproduce the problem with a less code : http://jsfiddle.net/uQC9U/ .

i have tried this : [solution for extra space in div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170048/solution-for-extra-space-in-div-element) and [JQuery mobile bottom space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908635/jquery-mobile-bottom-space) .

```
   <html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<BODY>
<div data-role="page" id="homepage" >


<div>                                      
  <form method='post' id='registerform' action='index.php'>                                          
      <label  class='error' id='registererrorA' > </label>       
           <button type='Submit' id='registerbttn' name='registerbttn' data-theme='c'>Register</button>              
     </form>                                                                                        

</div>
</div>
</BODY>
</html>
```

and i have played around with the following code :

```
- html, body, div, span, object, iframe,   h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
   blockquote, pre,   table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
          }
 - div { margin:0; padding:0; }
 - #page {
       text-align: center;
       border-bottom: solid 1px #FFC;
       height: auto;
       padding: 0;
       bottom: 0; }
```

P.S. Forgive my English

i am not allowed to post a solution into my post but i have found a solution:
i changed this :

```
<button type='Submit' id='registerbttn' name='registerbttn' data-theme='c'>Register</button>
```

into

```
<input type='submit' id='registerbttn' name='registerbttn' data-theme='c' value='Register' />
```

and the extra space dissapeared .

Comment: I don't understand where the extra space is in your jsfiddle example.

Comment: On internet explorer it works fine, the spaces shows up on firefox 15.0.1 and opera 12.11 .

Comment: I know it's not ideal but the following will get the desired result. `<div data-role="page" id="homepage" style="bottom:-75%;">` This worked for me in IE and Firefox.